# How to embed android contact to MY application

Tags: android

I want to access contacts in my app and don't want to start the native app, but write my own contacts listview  and processing filter is too much tricky.

So is it possible to embed the contactslistview into my application?

Answer (score 0):

No, you will need to write your own `ListView` working with the contacts data. [Here is a sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Contacts/Spinners/) loading some contact data into Spinner widgets.